# "zip" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом - Ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

Изучаю Python по книге "A byte of Python", и там есть программа по упаковке файла\директории, т.е создание неких резервных копий файлов. Вот код:

```
import os
import time

sourse = [r"D:\Files\Programming\python_develop\test_folder"]
target_dir = r'D:\Files\Programming\python_develop'
target = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'
zip_command = 'zip -qr {0} {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(sourse))

print(zip_command)
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print('Резервная копия создана в:', target)
else:
    print('ERROR')
```

При запуске файла с кодом выдает следующую ошибку: ""zip" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом."

Почему возникает данная ошибка?

Comment: Скажите  1. а что вам непонятно в тексте ошибки, который ясно говорит, почему она возникает? 2. Что вам помешало вбить в поиске текст ошибки и найти даже на этом сайте 100500 вопросов именно по этому коду из этой книги именно по такой же ошибке?

Comment: Вы очень невнимательно изучаете. Причина проблемы описывается ровно одной страницей раньше!

Answer (score -1):

*Почему возникает данная ошибка?* -  наверное потому, что в книге опечатка. Или потому, что хотят заставить читателя самостоятельно находить ошибки (первое умение любого программиста, без которого никак).

Запускать ваш код я не собираюсь, а где именно возникает ошибка - хотя интерпретатор вам это явно сказал, но нам вы сочли излишним эту информацию передать. Но тем не менее предполагаю, что в литерале '.zip' лишний пробел. Проверяйте.

Comment: Судя по коду, там проблема в том, что windows не находит команду zip.